# A .NET scripting tool to write quick 'ad hoc' code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console

I always find myself creating new projects in VS just to write a oneliner to test something out, or use it as a more dynamic calculator. Is there a tool out there that I can quickly open up, write my C# code and then see the result? Intellisense would be a nice option.

I remember using a C# python-mod addin for VS which was basically like a console that worked in a similar way, but I'd like to do it without creating projects etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a tool out there that I can quickly open up, write my C# code
>   and then see the result?

[LinqPAD](http://www.linqpad.net/) is defintely an option.

> Intellisense would be a nice option

The paid version of LinqPAD provides also an intellisence.

Answer (score 0):

[CsharpRepl](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl) or gsharp (GUI version)

Comment: Nice tool, thanks for the link. For this instance I think LINQPad is the better answer though.